# Firefox and Chromium snap on Ubuntu ARM64

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, chrome, arm

I am receiving the following errors when trying to run Firefox or Chromium browser on ARM64 Ubuntu instance:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-161:~/firefox$ firefox
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-161:~/firefox$ chromium
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

This is with debug turned on:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-161:~/firefox$ SNAPD_DEBUG=1 firefox
2023/08/13 19:12:32.995639 tool_linux.go:204: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/snapd/current/usr/bin/snap"
2023/08/13 19:12:33.010381 logger.go:92: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"start", "time":"1691953953.010376"}
2023/08/13 19:12:33.016586 logger.go:92: DEBUG: executing snap-confine from /snap/snapd/19127/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
2023/08/13 19:12:33.017338 logger.go:92: DEBUG: SELinux not enabled
2023/08/13 19:12:33.017712 logger.go:92: DEBUG: creating transient scope snap.firefox.firefox
2023/08/13 19:12:33.019178 logger.go:92: DEBUG: using session bus
2023/08/13 19:12:33.024157 logger.go:92: DEBUG: StartTransientUnit failed with "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited": [Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1]
2023/08/13 19:12:33.024807 logger.go:92: DEBUG: snapd cannot track the started application
2023/08/13 19:12:33.024856 logger.go:92: DEBUG: snap refreshes will not be postponed by this process
2023/08/13 19:12:33.024874 logger.go:92: DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap to snap-confine", "time":"1691953953.024868"}
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine enter", "time":"1691953953.029811"}
DEBUG: umask reset, old umask was   02
DEBUG: security tag: snap.firefox.firefox
DEBUG: executable:   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
DEBUG: confinement:  non-classic
DEBUG: base snap:    core22
DEBUG: ruid: 1000, euid: 0, suid: 0
DEBUG: rgid: 1000, egid: 1000, sgid: 1000
DEBUG: apparmor label on snap-confine is: /snap/snapd/19127/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
DEBUG: apparmor mode is: enforce
DEBUG: -- snap startup {"stage":"snap-confine mount namespace start", "time":"1691953953.042582"}
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope (global), uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: ensuring that snap mount directory is shared
DEBUG: unsharing snap namespace directory
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: releasing lock 5
DEBUG: opened snap-update-ns executable as file descriptor 5
DEBUG: opened snap-discard-ns executable as file descriptor 6
DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/firefox.lock
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope firefox, uid 0)
DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
DEBUG: initializing mount namespace: firefox
DEBUG: setting up device cgroup
DEBUG: libudev has current tags support
DEBUG: device /sys/devices/virtual/mem/full has matching current tag
DEBUG: get bpf object at path /sys/fs/bpf/snap/snap_firefox_firefox
DEBUG: found existing device map
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: get next key for map 8
DEBUG: found 17 existing entries in devices map
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:2
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:7
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:9
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 137:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 10:200
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 136:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 143:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 142:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:8
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:3
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 138:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 141:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 139:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 140:-1
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 1:5
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: delete key for c 5:0
DEBUG: delete elem in map 8
DEBUG: load program of type 0xf, 33 instructions
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:3
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:5
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:8
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:9
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:0
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:1
DEBUG: v2 allow c 5:2
DEBUG: v2 allow c 136:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 137:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 138:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 139:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 140:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 141:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 142:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 143:4294967295
DEBUG: v2 allow c 10:200
DEBUG: inspecting type of device: /dev/full
DEBUG: v2 allow c 1:7
DEBUG: process in cgroup /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

Any advice on what is going on here?